# Programmatically call another .apk file from current application?

Tags: android, apk

Is it possible to programmatically call another .apk file from my current Application in Android?

Comment: To answer your question, yes, it's possible. Of course you probably didn't mean to ask a yes/no question and would like to know how to do this - but that question is too broad. What does "call another .apk" mean to you? There are multiple possibilities with different solutions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try as:

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new 
        File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/path/" 
        + "app_apk.apk")), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
        CurrentActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: @mah : he is asking for calling an .apk from own application then  maybe possible he us asking for installing an .apk from own appliction??

Comment: `calling an .apk` -- via service? just launching an activity (through action? class/name? etc.? starting an activity for result? perhaps simply sending a broadcast would meet his needs? Until you know his needs (which he failed to mention) you have no reasonable way to answer him (and with regards to simply starting some remote activity, your answer is so far from being helpful I have to seriously wonder if the upvote you received was your own doing).

Comment: As to "asking for installing a .apk from his own application" I'll assume English is not your first language and I simply don't understand your, as the notion of what your chosen words suggest is really preposterous without having far more of a question than what the poster provided.

Comment: Say ,I have  2 applications onto my sdcard namely location.apk and detect.apk. Now from my location program i would want the detect application to run/execute which will basically take images.