# One apk will be called from another apk(wrapper solution)

Tags: android

I want to build an apk file which can add extra another apk with wrraper solution. how can i do that please help me

Or ,one apk will be called from another apk(wrapper solution).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Programmatically call another .apk file from current application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11491333/programmatically-call-another-apk-file-from-current-application)

Comment: File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/path/" 
        + "app_apk.apk")),     what mean + "/path/" +   where I can put  my apk  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to call one .apk from your application. If .apk file is installed in your device then use that .apk file's Package name to Launch that apk . use this

```
  Intent launchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(PackageName);
            startActivity(launchIntent);
```